# Создал динамические pictureBox, но привязать событие не получается

Tags: c#, winforms, события, picturebox

Создал динамические pictureBox, но привязать событие не получается. Что делаю не так не понимаю. Код прилагаю

```
using OilsGuid.Properties;
using System;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace OilsGuid
{
    public partial class Home : Form
    {
        public Home()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            Load_Menu();
            pic6.Click += new EventHandler(this.pic6_Click);
        }
        private void Load_Menu()
        {
            this.panel1.Controls.Add(new PictureBox
            {
                Anchor = AnchorStyles.None,
                Image = Resources.рецепт,
                Location = new Point(52, 23),
                Name = "pic1",
                Size = new Size(166, 150),
                SizeMode = PictureBoxSizeMode.Zoom
            }) ;
            this.panel1.Controls.Add(new Label
            {
                Anchor = AnchorStyles.None,
                Font = new Font("Malgun Gothic", 10.8F, FontStyle.Regular, GraphicsUnit.Point, ((byte)(0))),
                Location = new Point(90, 178),
                Name = "label1",
                Size = new Size(91, 28),
                TabIndex = 1,
                Text = "текст",
                TextAlign = ContentAlignment.MiddleCenter
            });
            this.panel1.Controls.Add(new PictureBox
            {
                Anchor = AnchorStyles.None,
                Image = Resources.применение,
                Location = new Point(233, 23),
                Name = "pic2",
                Size = new Size(166, 150),
                SizeMode = PictureBoxSizeMode.Zoom
            });
            this.panel1.Controls.Add(new Label
            {
                Anchor = AnchorStyles.None,
                Font = new Font("Malgun Gothic", 10.8F, FontStyle.Regular, GraphicsUnit.Point, ((byte)(0))),
                Location = new Point(251, 178),
                Name = "label2",
                Size = new Size(130, 56),
                TabIndex = 1,
                Text = "текст",
                TextAlign = ContentAlignment.MiddleCenter
            });
            this.panel1.Controls.Add(new PictureBox
            {
                Anchor = AnchorStyles.None,
                Image = Resources.два,
                Location = new Point(416, 23),
                Name = "pic3",
                Size = new Size(166, 150),
                SizeMode = PictureBoxSizeMode.Zoom
            });
            this.panel1.Controls.Add(new Label
            {
                Anchor = AnchorStyles.None,
                Font = new Font("Malgun Gothic", 10.8F, FontStyle.Regular, GraphicsUnit.Point, ((byte)(0))),
                Location = new Point(421, 178),
                Name = "label3",
                Size = new Size(156, 56),
                TabIndex = 1,
                Text = "Текст",
                TextAlign = ContentAlignment.MiddleCenter
            });
            this.panel1.Controls.Add(new PictureBox
            {
                Anchor = AnchorStyles.None,
                Image = Resources.один,
                Location = new Point(52, 251),
                Name = "pic4",
                Size = new Size(166, 150),
                SizeMode = PictureBoxSizeMode.Zoom
            });
            this.panel1.Controls.Add(new Label
            {
                Anchor = AnchorStyles.None,
                Font = new Font("Malgun Gothic", 10.8F, FontStyle.Regular, GraphicsUnit.Point, ((byte)(0))),
                Location = new Point(56, 408),
                Name = "label4",
                Size = new Size(151, 50),
                TabIndex = 1,
                Text = "Текст",
                TextAlign = ContentAlignment.MiddleCenter
            });
            this.panel1.Controls.Add(new PictureBox
            {
                Anchor = AnchorStyles.None,
                Image = Resources.избранное,
                Location = new Point(233, 251),
                Name = "pic5",
                Size = new Size(166, 150),
                SizeMode = PictureBoxSizeMode.Zoom
            });
            this.panel1.Controls.Add(new Label
            {
                Anchor = AnchorStyles.None,
                Font = new Font("Malgun Gothic", 10.8F, FontStyle.Regular, GraphicsUnit.Point, ((byte)(0))),
                Location = new Point(455, 408),
                Name = "label5",
                Size = new Size(88, 28),
                TabIndex = 1,
                Text = "Заметки",
                TextAlign = ContentAlignment.MiddleCenter
            });
            this.panel1.Controls.Add(new PictureBox
            {
                Anchor = AnchorStyles.None,
                Image = Resources.заметки,
                Location = new Point(416, 251),
                Name = "pic6",
                Size = new Size(166, 150),
                SizeMode = PictureBoxSizeMode.Zoom
            } );
            this.panel1.Controls.Add(new Label
            {
                Anchor = AnchorStyles.None,
                Font = new Font("Malgun Gothic", 10.8F, FontStyle.Regular, GraphicsUnit.Point, ((byte)(0))),
                Location = new Point(258, 408),
                Name = "label6",
                Size = new Size(117, 28),
                TabIndex = 1,
                Text = "Избранное",
                TextAlign = ContentAlignment.MiddleCenter
            });
        }
        private void pic6_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            panel1.Visible = false;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: "но привязать событие не получается." - У вас нет кода, который "привязывает" события к контролам `PictureBox`, если только Вы не ожидаете, что событие "привяжется" само, потому что Вы написали `Name = "pic6",`, а метод называется `pic6_Click`. Не привяжется.

Comment: Не понял. Что не правильно то?

Comment: Не торопитесь. Медленно перечитайте комментарий и ответ. Подумайте.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

"но привязать событие не получается." - У вас нет кода, который "привязывает" события к динамически создаваемым контролам `PictureBox`, если только Вы не ожидаете, что событие "привяжется" само, потому что Вы написали `Name = "pic6",`, а метод называется `pic6_Click`. Не привяжется.

```
        PictureBox pb6 = new PictureBox
        {
            Anchor = AnchorStyles.None,
            Image = Resources.заметки,
            Location = new Point(416, 251),
            //Name = "pic6",
            Size = new Size(166, 150),
            SizeMode = PictureBoxSizeMode.Zoom
        }; 
        pb6.Click += new EventHandler(this.pic6_Click);
        this.panel1.Controls.Add(pb6);
```

Comment: Благодарю, Игорь!

Comment: @Георгий Пожалуйста. Успехов.